# How can I safely clean Stan's tubeless tyre sealant from carbon rims?

Tags: rims, carbon, tubeless, sealant

I had a minor accident and spilled a lot of Stan's tubeless sealant on my carbon rims, which has unfortunately dried and become quite difficult to remove. What is the easiest and safest way to get dried sealant off carbon rims without damaging them? I guess alcohol might do the trick, but I am a bit afraid that it may damage decals and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stan's is WATER SOLUABLE.  Clean it with water.  Some mild soap may help if it's stubborn.

[Stan's FAQ](https://www.notubes.com/faqs)